# Como ordenar animações com jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animação

Tenho este código e queria ordenar as animações, para que a do `header` só comece depois que a do `.logo_1` terminar. Tentei usar duration mas não deu muito certo, tem alguma outra forma de eu ordenar as animações?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.mini_botao').click(function(){
        $(".logo_1").animate({marginTop: '-150px'}, 1000);
        $("header").animate({marginTop: '0'}, 3000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Você quer começar uma animação só depois que a outra terminar, é isso?

Comment: Correto @bfavaretto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tente um [**delay**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) antes*

```
$("header").delay(2500).animate({marginTop: '0'}, 1000);
```

***Referências:***

- [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)
- [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: Delay vai ser a alternativa certa, vou fazer mais algumas implementações e o callback não vai servir pra min.

Answer (score 6):

Adicione um callback na primeira animação, pra daí então utilizar a segunda.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.mini_botao').click(function(){
        $(".logo_1").animate({marginTop: '-150px'}, 1000, function() {
            $("header").animate({marginTop: '0'}, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Fico mais ou menos, ainda estou precisando usar um duration com diferença de mil pra as animações não saírem juntas.

Comment: @Josimara esta solução que o Cahe apresentou resolve seu problema, após realizar a primeira animação, é chamada a segunda.